# "Windows Command Processor has Stopped Working" error when starting cmd.exe

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Suddenly, whenever I start the Windows 10 command prompt (cmd.exe), I get this error:

[image]

Followed by:

[image]

This is very annoying because I am a technical Windows 10 user, and find the command prompt very useful for various tasks. I haven't really messed with my system too much, and no internet sources seem to provide a working fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: This happens whether I run it as admin or not BTW.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the event logs?

Comment: The exception code is 0xc0000005. Full error: http://pastebin.com/raw/HMuCc9MW

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have fixed this, but it turns out the problem was my own stupidity. I had just accidentally inserted characters into a system DLL, instead of over-writing them. Of course this changed all the function addresses and yeah, stopped my command line (and I'm sure many other things) from working. Luckily I had a back-up and it fixed it. **For anyone having this problem, think back, did you change any system files? If so, revert them to your backup. If you don't have a backup, you shouldn't be editing system files, and this should be a lesson to you :)**